# Click handler not firing for elements rendered in Ajax Callback - only in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, safari

I am having trouble getting something wo work in Safari (and on ios devices) that works fine on Firefox, Chrome, Edge and IE.

On my page there is an input field that sends input back to the server and adds an element to the dom after the server created this element (think of it as a complex combobox with server side rendering of search results).

This dom element that's added to the page contains clickable links like this one

```
<a href="" class="stampOption">Search result 1</a>
```

Since nobody knows how many of these links will be present on a page, I register a a click handler on the document like this:

$(document).on("click touchstart tap", function(evt) {

```
if ($(evt.target).hasClass("stampOption")) {

                some code...    
});
```

While this is fine in all Browsers I've tested so far, the click handler is never called in Safari.

I've tried several alternatives like delegated events (which also seem to have problems on Safari/iOS) like so:

```
$(document).on("click touchstart tap", ".stampOption", function(evt) {
```

. And I applied the cursor:pointer CSS trick as well as the onclick="" trick that is suggested here on SO and elsewhere.

I also made sure no other click event handler prevents bubbling or such.

So any ideas what else I could try?

Comment: try give the href a `#` and prevent the default action of the link - I think safari may have a problem with links without a href

Comment: +Pete unfortunaly, this doesn't help. The href is not being navigated to and the click handler is not called at all. Just like before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. The problem was a blur handler on the same page that used relatedTarget, which, on Safari, was always Null, so some if()-statement never came to the right conclusion on Safari, while all was well in other Browsers.
Let's say some handler ate away the click event on Safari. A typical case of ignorance towards Browser incompatibilities...